# How to Apply Conditional Formatting Based on Adjacent Cell Value for Entire Column?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I am looking to apply conditional formatting to all cells in a column (excluding the header) where a colour will be applied depending on if its value is greater, equal, or less than the adjacent cell.

Simple example:

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 200 |
| 2 | 50 | 150 |
| 3 | 80 | 20 |
| ... | ... | ... |

Here is a simple spreadsheet that is more complex implementing @Rubén's solution:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pl_UOyyE8r-JOcGWM2zsA2fFAbuvH3EUg7YnonaTZqY/edit?usp=sharing

Range `B:B` has the following custom formulas:

- `=B2>=A2` for green (if the cell on the right is *greater than or equal to* the cell on the left)
- `=B2<A2` for red (if the cell on the right is *less than* the cell on the left)

If the value in column `B` is *greater than or equal to* the value in column `A`, colour the `B` cell green. If the value in column `B` is *less than* the value in column `A`, colour the `B` cell red.

So rows `1` and `2` should be green, and `3` red.

I am familiar with how to do this individually on a per cell basis, but if I have hundreds of rows and need to do this over multiple columns I don't want to manually do this hundreds of times. It looks like I need to use the *Custom formula is* on *Conditional formatting rules*, but I can't figure out how to target a relative cell by position.

---

What I've tried:

- Conditional formatting on one cell such as `Great than or equal to` `$A2`, then dragging this row down hoping the `2` increments. It doesn't. This also wouldn't work in scenarios where there are unique formulas or static values in the cells without going back and updating the cell values.
- Using the `Custom formula is`, but unable to find the correct function to pair it with to again make that `2` value increment. Looked at [MATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378?hl=en) and other descriptions of functions and didn't see anything suitable for dynamic cell.
- Looked at using the *Script Editor*, but this didn't seem right and seemed like overkill for what I feel is pretty simple.
- Googling, but somehow not finding anyone who's wanted to do this before. Stack has questions that are close, such as [Conditional Formatting based on other column](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/120501/conditional-formatting-based-on-other-column) that also use the `MATCH` function, but I wasn't able to make this work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use the following formula

`=B2>=A2` for green (if the cell on the right is greater than or equal to the cell on the left)

```
=AND(B2>=A2,B2<>"")
```

`=B2<A2` for red (if the cell on the right is less than the cell on the left)

```
=AND(B2<A2,B2<>"")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Either the Apply to range or the formulas are wrong.

- Instead of `B:B` use `B2:B`

OR

- Instead of `B2>=A2` it should be `B1>=A1`
- Instead of `B2<A2` it should be `B1>A1`

---

1. Apply to range you might select the whole column B
2. Use a custom formula with relative references i.e. B1 instead or $B$1

First rule

[image]

Second rule

[image]

Related

- [How to conditional format in Google sheets based on cell directly above it?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/88335/88163)
- [Google sheets conditional formatting relative to another cell in the same column](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/102387/88163)